# (Non)complete abelian groups in the “transfinite p-adic topology”

Tags: gr.group-theory, topological-groups, p-adic-groups, abelian-groups, completion

For an abelian group $A,$ a prime $p$ and an ordinal $\alpha,$ we recursively define  $p^\alpha A$ as a subgroup of $A$ such that $p^0A=A,$
$$p^{\alpha+1}A=p(p^\alpha A) \hspace{5mm} \text{and} \hspace{5mm}  p^\lambda A= \bigcap_{\alpha<\lambda} p^\alpha A$$
for a limit ordinal $\lambda.$
It is known that for any ordinal $\alpha$ there is an abelian group $A$ such that $p^\beta A\ne p^\alpha A$ for $\beta<\alpha$ (it is related to Ulm’s theorems, see also Example 3.2 in Chapter 11 in "Fuchs. Abelian groups. Springer, 2015").

For a limit ordinal $\lambda$ we define the $p$-adic $\lambda$-completion as a limit
$$ \hat{A}^\lambda_p = \underset{\alpha<\lambda}{\rm lim} \: A/p^\alpha A.$$
In these terms the ordinary $p$-adic completion is the $p$-adic $\omega$-completion.

We say that an abelian group $A$ is $p$-adic $\lambda$-quasi-complete, if the the map $A\to \hat A^\lambda_p$ is an epimorphism. I am interested in examples of abelian groups which are quasi-complete with respect to some countable limit ordinal and not quasi-complete with respect to some bigger countable limit ordinal.

Modifying the example from the book of Fuchs, I can construct an example of an abelian group $A$ such that for any limit countable ordinal $\lambda$ it is $p$-adic $\lambda$-quasi-complete and $p^\lambda A \ne p^{\lambda+1}A.$ But I would like to see an example of an abelian group $A$ which is $\omega$-quasi-complete but not $\lambda$-quasi-complete for some countable limit ordinal $\lambda>\omega.$

**Question:** Is there an abelian group $A$ which is $p$-adic $\omega$-quasi-complete but not $p$-adic $(\omega+\omega)$-quasi-complete?